# ceil() and floor() functions in C++ for size_t types

Tags: c++, size-t, floor, ceil

I have two variables:

```
size_t a = 63;
size_t b = 32;
```

I called the function `ceil(a/b)`.  Naturally I would assume that the answer returns `2` but instead it returns `1`.

I'm puzzled. I have tried casting the variables to a *double* or *int* and it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you casting? Casting works fine for me ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down what happens when you do `ceil(a/b)`. First, an integer division happens between a and b, so 63/32 becomes (int)1, and then this 1 is casted to double to become 1.0, and then ceil(1.0) is of course just 1.0.

If you expect to get 2, you need to convert to double before the division occurs, i.e. `ceil(double(a) / double(b))` uses double division.

Answer (score 1):

The `ceil` and `floor` functions work on `double` types.  You have done an integer division (because `size_t` is an integer type), so the result is an integer (*ie* it's already a whole number, so you cannot round up or down).  Try casting to `double` before the division:

```
ceil( double(a) / double(b) );
floor( double(a) / double(b) );
```

You technically only need to cast the first one, because then you will get floating-point division instead.  But it's good to be explicit and cast both.

Answer (score 0):

Both 63 and 32 are ints, hence the result will be an int (i.e. 1 and not 1.96875).

Either typecast it as specified by paddy or

or use double values

```
ceil(63.0/32); // promotes 32 from int to double since one of the operand(63.0) is double.
ceil(63.0/32.0); // both operands are doubles
```

Answer (score 0):

`a/b` will perform an integer division since they are *integral* types, which will result in `1`, this explains why [std::ceil](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) returns the value you are seeing. if we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `5.6` *Multiplicative operators* paragraph *4* says(*emphasis mine*):

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined. **For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded**;[...]

casting either of the operands to *double* will be sufficient due to *arithmetic conversions* which are covered in section `5` *Expressions* paragraph *10* which says(*emphasis mine*):

> **Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way**. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is **called the usual arithmetic conversions**, which are defined as follows:

and includes this bullet:

> Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double.

So the following expression will yield the result you desire:

```
std::ceil( double(a)/b)
```